# Letsencrypt dosen't recogonize my domain name

Tags: dns, lets-encrypt

letsencrypt dosen't recogonize my domain name and it throws the below error while running docker-compose from the below link

https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
contain(s) the right IP address.
ERROR: Cert does not exist! Please see the validation error above. The issue may be due to incorrect dns or port forwarding settings. Please fix your settings and recreate the container

Comment: First check : 1) dns lookup is actually mapping to your ip 2) Your certificate uses the correct server dns address 2) port 443 is open

Comment: This may help, good luck. https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag/issues/53